# reusing spring beans - name collisions

Tags: spring, javabeans, collision, uniqueidentifier

What is the preffered approach for reusing other jar containing spring-annotated classes in spring (3.2) ?

Example of a problem:
I have a jar that has @Autowired SessionFactory, but it needs different session factory than the rest of the application (it talks to a different database)

So, if I just put that jar in my classpath the application won't start because there are 2 beans with the same type/name. I need to have that jar isolated from the rest of the application.
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting a particular bean when multiple candidates are present is addressed by `@Qualifier`. Just declare the same beans in your application context and assign them with different id's or qualifier names. Lets take a look at this class:

```
public class Foo{

     @Autowired
     private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
}
```

Assuming both `SessionFactoryImpl1` and `SessionFactoryImpl2` are both candidates for bean wiring, and you want to point sessionFactory to `SessionFactoryImpl1` instance instead, then you need to add the `@Qualifier` annotation just like in the example below:

```
public class Foo{

     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("sessionFactory1")
     private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
}
```

And in your application context

```
<bean class="example.SessionFactoryImpl1">
    <qualifier value="sessionFactory1"/>
    <!-- inject any dependencies required by this bean -->
</bean>

<bean class="example.SessionFactoryImpl2">
    <qualifier value="sessionFactory2"/>
    <!-- inject any dependencies required by this bean -->
</bean>
```

Comment: This can work for small application, but not when you have hundereds of lines of code. SessionFactory is an example, there will be more. Isn't there any way to tell spring that specific set of classes (everything in a given jar) should have a seperate context?

Comment: Do you mean to say that I can force a qualifier on annotated library code? 

This ambiguity is exactly why I don't annotate library code with things like @Autowired. You have no idea how that bean may need to be used

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno You'd share your strategy for handling library code that make use of beans ? If you don't annotate library code, then how you do the wiring ?